# How to resolve 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route' error while debugging in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, xdebug

I've created one controller with web route. If I put a request in browser I am getting my output, but when I tried to debug I am getting a following error in debug console:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route' not found in /home/payarc/Desktop/myDummy/routes/web.php:21
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/payarc/Desktop/myDummy/routes/web.php on line 21

How to resolve this error?

`web.php`

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/div',[UserController::class,'dummy']);
```

`UserController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function dummy(){
        $a=5;
        $b=0;
        $c=$a+$b;
        echo $c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Route.php` exist?

Comment: @aynber, yeah it's present

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload` to see if that will help

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Script Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump handling the post-autoload-dump event terminated with an exception  . i am getting this error when i run composer dumpautoload

Comment: Is there any other information with that?

Comment: n platform_check.php line 24:
                                                                                                                                                                        
  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.2.34-24+0~20210826.64+debian9~1.gbp428dfa.      This one is available with that

Comment: You need to update your version of PHP, then, to at least 7.3.0. The project did not install correctly because your version of PHP is too low

Answer (score 0):

In your project check app.php file, you should keep the below line on the 'aliases' array:

```
'Route'     => "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route",
```

Comment: Hope you have installed Laravel correctly, cross-check and see the video I'm attaching below might be able to help you out.
https://youtu.be/7YezCyBbqI0

Comment: What version of php are you using?  Did you run composer install?  delete the vendor folder and reinstall with composer install.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error,
you are running with wrong php file
change URL in run/debug wizard to index.php
[image]